# access denied for HtmlElement inside class function

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a function that loops through a group of links in vb.net:

```
For Each category As HtmlElement In fs.cats
   fs.run_fetch(category)
   outToCSV(fs.results, "C:\Data\test.csv")
   outToCSV(fs.errors, "C:\Data\errors.csv")
Next
```

It works fine for the first loop but once it enters the second loop fs.run_fetch(category) gives me ***Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))*** when trying to run the following

```
Public Sub run_fetch(ByVal category As HtmlElement)
        Dim itemsonpage As HtmlElementCollection
        Dim title, id, salePrice, regPrice As String
        Dim numberOnSale, currentPage As Integer
        'navigate to category page
        loadPage(category.GetAttribute("href")) **<- error here**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this may be obvious to some however, a variable defined as a HTMLElement or HTMLElementCollection in vb.net is always a **reference**.

As a result, when you **navigate** to a different page **the reference to the variables is lost** (ie the webpage your variables were referencing no longer exists "in memory" and the references become obsolete)

My solution was to save the links (urls that I pulled off the webpage) into a list(of strings) and as such they no longer reference the page and are in memory until you clear it.